# Styles moved to the folder?

Tags: angular, web

My app works fine when URL have one word (ex. /Home, /login etc.). But if I run /confirm/token styles moves to the folder. Why?
styles on the server when I open:

[image: styles on the server when I open]

My routing:
routes:

[image: routes]

**UPD:** Need to byild with flag `--deploy-url`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use baseHref to specify correct url